# How to set logging level for spring cloud config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am trying to debug some issues I'm having with my spring cloud configuration, but I'm not sure how to correctly set the logging level for it. I have tried setting the logging level `"org.springframework.cloud` to trace, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. What is the correct package for logging spring cloud?

**Update**
I'm hoping to see basic information like if properties were found.

**Update2**
The issue turned out to be related to my JBoss appender. I was setting the log level of the correct package, but the logging level of the console appender was set to info, so none of the cloud config info was being logged.

Comment: What are you hoping to see? My answer below points out there isn't much from the client side. Add some detail to the question and I may be able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 9):

Example using `.yml` file:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.cloud.config: DEBUG
```

By the way, if you are debugging from the client, there isn't a ton of code:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/tree/master/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config

So, whatever you are hoping for may be in a different package.

Answer (score 2):

We have to set the Log configuration details in .yml file as shown below

```
logging:
  file: D:/PathToLogFile/configuration-server.log
  level:
    ROOT: 'INFO'
  config: classpath:logback-springtest.xml
```

Here is complete logback-springtest.xml defination.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level [%thread] %logger{10} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```